# lightning:empApi is not working in summer19's sandbox: 403::Unknown client

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, streaming-api, cometd

I am receiving errors in lightning:empApi in the console. It was working fine before summer19 release in the sandbox. It works fine in scratch org. Scratch org is also on summer19.

The error is attached:

> Received error 
>   {"advice":{"interval":0,"reconnect":"handshake"},"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"7","error":"403::Unknown
>   client","successful":false}

[image]:

Comment: Could you please provide you simplest code you reproduce that problem?

Comment: @Patlatus the code is taken from on this trailhead unit. 
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/workshop-platform-events/platform-event-subscribe#testtheinstantnotificationapp

Update on this: Error is still sometimes coming but now the payload has started working as well. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: I am also getting this error. If I create a new component and use the example from the [lightning:empApi documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) exactly, it gives the 403 handshake error. I'm in a sandbox, api v46. This will happen with both Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @VishnuKumar were you able to resolve the issue. Can you guide me please. I saw your package though but i need to understand why we have this issue